# HTML5 type week in vb.net how can I get the value?

Tags: html, vb.net, types

I have this type week control on my page, it fires an event on Page Load, but how can I get its value? txtSettimana.text is empty and there's no "value" property I can choose.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSettimana" Type="week" ToolTip="Data" required="required" AutoPostBack="true" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

`txtSettimana.Text` will be null string (empty as you said) in the Page Load event **for the first time** because no value is set to it yet.

Let's say, you also have a `<asp:Button>` in your page, then you select the week in your `txtSettimana` and click the button, then it will trigger the Button Click event.

In the Button Click event, you will get the value of `txtSettimana.Text`.

Clicking the button will also trigger the Page Load event as the second time.
At this time you can also get the value of `txtSettimana.Text`.